# How to install SideWaffle to VS2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sidewaffle

I downloaded the extension from [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a16c2d07-b2e1-4a25-87d9-194f04e7a698) and when I doubleclicked on the `vsix` package nothnig happened.

I checked out the `extension.manifest` file in the package, and these are the supported version there:

```
<Installation>
  <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="11.0" />
  <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="12.0" />
  <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="14.0" />
</Installation>
```

When VS Community got out, you had to do [this](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/installing-ef-power-tools-into-vs2015/) to get EF Power Tools to work, but `SideWaffle` uses the 2.0 manifest version and that doesn't work.

I tries adding `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community` but that didn't work either. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Community acts as Pro with regards to extensions. Any Pro extension should install on Community. Have you tried looking SideWaffle up in the extension gallery?

Comment: The extension gallery took me to the Visual Studio Gallery site. I installed it using the Development Command Promt, have a look at my answer

Comment: Yes Pro should also install into Community edition as well. sidewaddle.com redirects to download bits from VS gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why it didn't install when I ran it, but I did find a workaround:

Open `Developer Command Prompt for VS2015` and run `VSIXInstaller {path to vsix file}`

That did the trick.